# Why the result of score() and accuracy_score() are different?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, classification, svm, hyperparameters

I was doing classification with Support Vector Machine (SVM)

And

```
df=pd.read_csv('mobile.csv')
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

model = SVC()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

```
model.score(x_test, y_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
accuracy
```

model.score(x_test, y_test) result was 0.9533333333333334
And accuracy score was also 0.9533333333333334

And then I tried to make better with hyperparameter.

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

C_values = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]

train_scores = []
test_scores = []

for C in C_values:
    model = SVC(C=C)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    train_scores.append(model.score(x_train, y_train))
    test_scores.append(model.score(x_test, y_test))

model.score(x_test, y_test)
```

And then I could find model.score(x_test, y_test) result became 0.9716666666666667

```
accuracy
```

However, the accuracy score hasn't change, it was still 0.9533333333333334

I'm not sure this is normal or not.

Do you have idea why this happened?

I thought the result of score() and accuracy_score() are always have same value.

But it was not for now

I'm not sure if there is something wrong or not.

I checked the time when score() value change was after using hyperparameter. So I expected that something is wrong of the processing of hyperparameter.

Comment: In your code, you are defining `y_pred` before tuning the model, so the predictions are made with the original (not tuned) model, hence the method `accuracy_score()` will return the original accuracy

Answer (score 0):

The method `accuracy_score()` takes as input the test and the predictions. The problem here is that you are computing the predictions before the loop with the tuning.

Also, `model.score()` outside the for loop doesn't make much sense, as it will use the last tuned model (that could not be the best one).

You can nest it inside the loop in order to print each result, together with computing the predictions and print also the accuracy, that will be the same as the `model.score()`

Comment: I put `y_pred = model.predict(x_test)` after hyperparameter processing and then score() and accuracy_score showed same value 0.9716666666666667, Thank you. But I still didn't get here "Also, model.score() outside the for loop doesn't make much sense, as it will use the last tuned model (that could not be the best one).

You can nest it inside the loop in order to print each result, together with computing the predictions and print also the accuracy, that will be the same as the model.score()"

Comment: As answer, shall I modify For loop in hyparameter processing?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do with your code. In this case you are appending the scores into the lists, that's ok, but I don't understand the last line `model.score(x_test, y_test)`, since it is outside the loop, so that model will always be the last one defined in the loop, regardless of the score itself. So I'm just not getting the point of doing that, but that's outside the original question

Comment: I see, I might try to use loop to print each result and print within loop, thank you so much for your answer

Comment: If you think that it solved your problem, please mark it as the correct one and upvote, thanks!